# update and get new state from setState Hook with Jest

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-hooks, jestjs, enzyme

I succeed to create a functional component, to mock the useState function and to get the call to the mocking function. But the functional component keep its initial value. Is there no way at all to get the new functional component created after update with its new initial "useState" value ?

For example, if I do an "simulate(click)" with enzyme twice on the button in the code below, I will have twice the value "1" returned in the mock function.

This limits a lot possible tests.

```
function Example() {

  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Vous avez cliqué {count} fois</p>
      <button id="count-up" onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Cliquez ici
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

here's my test code :

```
import React, { useState as useStateMock, setState } from 'react';

import { shallow, mount, render } from 'enzyme';

import Example from './file with example component'

jest.mock('react', () => ({
    ...jest.requireActual('react'),
    useState: jest.fn(),
}));

describe('<Home />', () => {
    let wrapper;

    const setState = jest.fn();

    beforeEach(async () => {
        useStateMock.mockImplementation(init => [init, setState]);
        wrapper = mount(<Example />)
    });


    describe('Count Up', () => {
        it('calls setCount with count + 1', () => {
            
            wrapper.find('#count-up').first().simulate('click');
            expect(setState).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith(1);
            wrapper.find('#count-up').simulate('click');
            expect(setState).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith(2);
        });
    });
})
```

I would like the setState mock function to return 1 then 2 as its corresponds to the initial state 0 + 1 and then this results 1 + 1 again.
But the functional component is not updated, and I don't know how to do that.
Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you show the test code? What did you get and what do you expect?

Comment: Thanks for answering, I updated my questions, tell me if you have enough to reproduce it

Answer (score 0):

Because you mock `useState` without providing an implementation, the functionality of `useState` has changed.

Don't mock the `react` module and its implementations. Continue to use their original implementation. You should test the component behavior instead of the implementation detail.

In other words, we want to test from the user's point of view, they don't care about your implementation, they just care about what they can see on the screen.

Component behavior is: What does your component render when the state changes.

So the unit test should be:

`Example.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';

export function Example() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Vous avez cliqué {count} fois</p>
      <button id="count-up" onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Cliquez ici
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

`Example.test.tsx`:

```
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import React from 'react';
import { Example } from './Example';

describe('70585877', () => {
  test('should pass', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<Example />);
    const button = wrapper.find('#count-up');
    // The initial state of the component as seen by the user
    expect(wrapper.find('p').text()).toEqual('Vous avez cliqué 0 fois');
    // User click the button
    button.simulate('click');
    // The next state of the component as seen by the user
    expect(wrapper.find('p').text()).toEqual('Vous avez cliqué 1 fois');
    // User click the button again
    button.simulate('click');
    // The next state of the component as seen by the user
    expect(wrapper.find('p').text()).toEqual('Vous avez cliqué 2 fois');
  });
});
```

Test result:

```sh
 PASS  examples/70585877/Example.test.tsx (9.532 s)
  70585877
    ✓ should pass (34 ms)

-------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File         | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files    |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 Example.tsx |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
-------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        10.519 s
```

Comment: Thank you but what happened if we can't get the "count" state from the text or any other visible things ? It's not supposed to happen ?